# How to show only articles written by users themselves through Devise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using full_calendar to show events based on user id.

I have an index of home that renders _form.html.erb of events, and creates events here.

And when I moved to the events/index with the calendar, I tried to show only events based on the user_id.

However, there are currently user id (1 ~ 3), but only events for user id (1) are shown. The events created by the rest of the user id are stored in the DB but are not visible in the calendar.

I would like to display only events according to user id in the calendar.

**Home controller**

```
def index
  @event = Event.new
  @events = Event.order("RANDOM()").first(1)
end
```

**index.html.erb (Home controller)**

```
<%= render partial: 'events/form', locals: { event: @event } %>
```

**_form.html.erb (Event controller)**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.input :color %>
    <%= f.input :start_time %>
    <%= f.input :end_time %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @event.user_id %>      
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_email, :value => @event.user_email %>      


  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**index.html.erb (Event controller)**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <section class="panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="calendar"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

<% @events.each do |x| %>
    <% if(x.user_id == current_user.id) %>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.8.1.min.js'></script>
        <script>
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
           header: {
                         left: 'prev,next today',
                         center: 'title',
                         right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                     },
                    events: '/events.json'
                });
        </script>
    <% else %>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.8.1.min.js'></script>
        <script>
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
           header: {
                         left: 'prev,next today',
                         center: 'title',
                         right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                     },
                });
        </script>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't understand what the if / else part is supposed to do in the events.each loop. Could you elaborate? You are also loading the jqeury library multiple times, not a very good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the following line in your Event model:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
```

And the reflection in the User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events
```

With these relations, you can simply do the following in your controller:

```
@events = current_user.events
```

Because `current_user` returns a `User` instance, and when you defined the `has_many :events` in the User model, Rails created this `events` instance method on User.

Comment: Thank you. This was the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but if you want to only show posts by a certain user, the easiest way is to use a scope in the model, and call that from a controller:

model scope

```
  class Calendar
    scope :by_user, -> (user) { where(user:user) }
  end
```

And use it in your controller:

```
 def index
   @calendars = Calendar.by_user(current_user)
 end
```

This will only fetch result for which user = current_user

Comment: I'm sorry. I just edited the code because it was not uploaded. Could you check it again?

Comment: The usage of a scope here is not the best option. A regular Rails relation will do the trick, and it the built-in solution of the framework

Comment: Why wouldn't a scope allow eager loads or joins? I think the syntax is a lot cleaner than writing `where(user:user)` on each call.

Comment: What about `user.events`?

Comment: Yes, that's indeed a better option, I agree.